# GITLAB - display the project name or source code repository name using advanced search

Tags: gitlab

I am new to using the advanced search option in gitlab.

I want to get a list of services (project name or source code) which has @KafkaListener in my gitlab.

I am able to search for @KafkaListener in gitlab which brings back 190 classes from various microservices but all I want is the name of the microservice i.e the name of the project.